having REPEAT with circuit append
In Stim's domain specific language, you can reapetdly add a code clock, as following
REPEAT 10 {
    # code block
}

Is there a way to add that with circuit.append()? Well one might say put a for loop behind that but that is not working, e.g. as the whole circuit is plotted in the circuit.diagram.

Multiplying a circuit by an integer larger than 1 turns it into a circuit with a loop, so you can do:
circuit += loop_body_circuit * repeat_count

or, if  you really specifically want to use append, you can do:
circuit.append(stim.CircuitRepeatBlock(
    body=loop_body_circuit,
    repeat_count=repeat_count,
))


Great, thank you.
